# Why does operator>> (or <<) overloading function need to receive an i\ostream reference?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

From cplusplus.com, I saw that `ostream` class's member function `operator<<` looks like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (bool val);   ostream& operator<< (int val);
```

.... and so on.

It does make sense because when you use the Cout object like  `cout<<x`  you activate the `ostream& operator<< (int val)`  function, so you actually use the `<<` operator on Cout object. This is very much like every other operator and sends the `int` variable to the function. What is the difference and what exactly happens when I want to stream an object of my own? Why does the syntax is suddenly `ostream& operator<< (**ostream &os**, object ob)`?
Why do I need to add the  `ostream` var? I am still using  `cout<<ob` so whay isnt it just    `ostream& operator<< (object obj)`? All I pass is my object. The `cout` object is allready there.

Comment: NO! its not my question.. somehow not all the text is shown here. there is not really a question in this text

Comment: You can [edit] your question if you think it is composed incorrectly.

Comment: I know but there is a problem.. the text is written fine but on the lower text box there is a missing text, and that lower text box it is what we see in here...

Comment: @user2162550 The problem is that you're talking about `operator<<`, and those angle brackets look like the beginning of a HTML tag. Limited HTML is allowed in posts on Stack Overflow, so those brackets were probably confusing the text renderer. I fixed it by code formatting the parts that mentioned `operator<<`.

Comment: Ok, worked. now, on one hand you are saying every operator<< gets ostram& var, but accourding to cplusplus.com: ostream& operator<< (int val); thats the signature for the primitive types!! whithout the ostream& var beeing sent!!

Comment: @user - Some operators are members of `ostream` and have the stream as the (hidden) `this` parameter. Others have the stream passed explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator<<` is generally defined as a free function; that is, not a member function. Since it is an overloaded binary operator, that means it get's its left argument first and its right argument second.

The `operator<<` traditionally returns a reference to its left argument to enable the idiomatic chain of output.

To make it obvious to the reader, I tend to define my `operator` overloads  using the `lhs` and `rhs` abbreviations; an `operator<<` would look similar to this, for some type `T`.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, T const& rhs)
{
    // TODO: Do something
    return lhs;
}
```

#### As a member function

As with other binary it could be defined as a member function. That is, let us suppose that you with defining your own `iostream`. Amongst other things, your class declaration may look like this. Again, `T` is a particular type.

```
class MyIOStream : public iostream
{

public:
    MyIOStream& operator<<(T const& rhs);

}
```

In this case `operator<<` is a member function. It has the same semantics when used as `<<`.

#### References

1. [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) - a great summary of all the operators you can overload and their typical arguments.

Comment: BUT whay doesnt the ostream& operator<< (bool val); gets also the ostream var??

Comment: @user2162550 Unfortunately, it does not; `ostream&` is the functions return type. It is the type of the variable you `return`.

Comment: I am talking about the variables the function gets! on one hand you are saying every operator<< gets ostram& var, but accourding to cplusplus.com   ostream& operator<< (int val);  thats the signature for the primitive types!! whithout the ostream& var beeing send!!

Comment: @user2162550 You appear very excited!!!!!!!!!! The basic types (probably) define them as member functions (see edit). However, I doubt the `std` requires them too. I suggest a good book (and far less reading of cplusplus.com).

Comment: and also according to cplusplus.com  this is indeed a member function

Answer (score 1):

> why do I need to add the ostream var?

I'm sure it's there so that you can chain outputs together:

```
cout << foo << bar
```

The first call, `cout << foo` will result in an `ostream` reference that can be used for the `<< bar` part.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the stream extractors are members of `basic_istream`; because they are members, the `basic_istream` argument is implied. Some of the stream extractors are not members of `basic_istream`. Because they are not members, the `basic_istream` argument has to be part of the declaration.

Like this (oversimplified):

```
class basic_istream {
public:
    basic_istream& operator>>(int& i);
}

basic_istream& operator>>(basic_istream&, std::string& str);
```

Both can be called in the same way:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i; // calls basic_istream::operator>>(int&)
std::string str;
std::cin >> str; // calls operator>>(basic_istrea&, std::string&)
```