# Misunderstanding about ostream class and operator <<

Tags: c++, iostream

After looking at the `ostream::operator <<` c++ reference,

I noticed the following declarations:

```
ostream& operator<< (bool val);
ostream& operator<< (short val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
ostream& operator<< (int val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
ostream& operator<< (long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
ostream& operator<< (float val);
ostream& operator<< (double val);
ostream& operator<< (long double val);
ostream& operator<< (void* val);
ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb );
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
ostream& operator<< (ios& (*pf)(ios&));
ostream& operator<< (ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&));
```

But then I found out that there are also the following declarations:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, char c);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, signed char c);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, unsigned char c);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const signed char* s);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const unsigned char* s);
```

Why are the char/string output operators not member functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does operator>> (or <<) overloading function need to receive an i\ostream reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003556/why-does-operator-or-overloading-function-need-to-receive-an-i-ostream-re)

Comment: @BoPersson, not a duplicate, that question is about user-defined types.

Answer (score 6):

The first group of operators are members of the  stream class.

Most operator overloads, like those in the second group, are not.

---

As to the *why*, it is likely just a historical accident. The operators for built in types *can* be added to the stream classes, and obviously they were (long before C++ was standardized). The standard just documents existing practice here.

Operators for user defined types obviously cannot be added to the stream classes, so they are implemented as free functions.

In retrospect it would have been more consistent to make all the operators free functions, but that would possibly break some old programs.

Comment: Do you know *why* those standard `char` overloads weren't made members of the stream class?

Comment: @DrewDormann Might be a good question on its own. I think to remember to already having seen problems (SO questions) caused indirectly by this distinction.

Comment: @ChristianRau from the comments here, I suspect *this question* is *that question*.

Comment: Yea, that's the main issue here ;)

Comment: @DrewDormann, I have a theory, feel free to comment on my answer if you think it makes no sense

Comment: @DrewDormann & Rouki Well, in that case the question needs some cleanup, clarifying that the OP is aware of the fact that one is a member and one is not and asking for the deeper reason. But both questions in one (and even without clarification which question it is) is bound to attract supposedly *"wrong"* or *"incomplete"* answers (like many of the exisiting ones *after* this clarification).

Comment: I probably shouldn't have asked both on the same topic.. anyhow, Ive edited the post.

Comment: @Bo, I disagree about historical accident. I think they can't be added to the class, as there are different implementations for `basic_ostream<char><<(char)` and `basic_ostream<wchar_t><<(char)` and you can't specialize a single member, thus global overloads.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic You can pretty well specialize individual members, just not by directly specializing them, but delegating parts of the work to other (possibly specialized) sub-components, like the char traits or the locale (which is what they're actually made for, abstracting char-type dependent functionality into smaller, specializable components). Think of a classical GoF *"template method"* (template in the GoF-sense, not the C++-sense).

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic - The historical accident is that `basic_ostream::operator<<(int)` is a member. It doesn't have to be.

Comment: @BoPersson, oh, right - I understood `The operators for built in types can be added to the stream classes` as refering to `char`.

Comment: @ChristianRau, sure but that's far more complex than having them as global functions

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic *"but that's far more complex than having them as global functions"* - Why. The char traits and locales are designed for exactly this purpose. Why make the stream and operators take them as template arguments when then *just not using them* and plainly doing the same operations they are supposed to do and can already do by plain function duplication. That's against all principles of code genericity and avoiding code duplication that build the base of the standard library's (and in general a good library's) design.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I'd prefer a single template method that has generic code (that doesn't depend on the stream and char types) only once and delegates specialized code to specialized traits (like it is done in the standard library), than a bunch of overloads doing exactly the same code parts over and over just for the sake of specilaizing certain small parts of the code (and completely ignoring the already given traits).

Answer (score 2):

The others have described the differences, here's my shot at why they are split.

The non-member versions, which take `char` variants as parameters are specialized depending on type of the target stream's base character type and handled depending on locale, because standard defines specific behavior (`o << '1'` has different behavior than `oo << 33`, it has to be handled properly if `o` is `basic_ostream<wchar_t>`, etc).

E.g. `char` writen to `basic_ostream<wchar_t>` is widened, while if written to `basic_ostream<char>` it is not (27.6.2.5.4). So actually there are multiple overloads of `operator<<`, e.g:

```
basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr, char _Ch)
basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& <<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr, char _Ch)
```

If they were defined as member functions, you wouldn't be able to specialize them like that as you would have to partially specialize the whole class, not just a single member, since standard doesn't allow partial specialization of member functions.

Comment: But then again you cannot specialize freestanding function templates (or at least you *couldn't* at the time those operators were added to the standard, but maybe in C++98 they weren't freestanding at all?). In the end you could customize them as easily (or maybe even easier) if they were member functions. And e.g. widening and such stuff is what specialized char traits and locales are for, no need to actually specialize the stream operators, I think.

Comment: Actually, this is not a partial specialization but overloading, right? I have edited the answer. The similar issue is discussed here: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two families of overloader `operator<<`s, as you have found out.

One family is the overloaded member `ostream::operator<<` (which gets the `ostream` reference implicitly as the `this` pointer) and the other family is the overloaded free function `operator<<` which gets the `ostream` reference explicitly as an argument.

When you want to add streaming capability to a class of your own, you add a free function.

Comment: Okay, and is there a good reason for why the output operators for char,unsigned,...,const unsigned char* are declared in different location?

Comment: @Rouki: One reason: assume you have an instance `s` of a class that is not an `ostream`, but has a conversion operator to `ostream`. If `operator<<` were just a member of `ostream` then `s << 1` would of course not compile. However, with the free function the compiler can see that there is a function that could match if `s` were an `ostream` -- and what do you know? There is a conversion operator it can use to do that! You will find many operators defined as free functions (e.g. see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/operators/)) for this reason.

Comment: The free functions do not forward to member functions - note they have different input types.  Subclassing is not a reason for this difference, since a reference-to-derived can convert to a reference-to-base either way.  I don't know the actual reason.

Comment: @aschepler: True, I had in mind the case where there might be polymorphic behavior. Corrected. Regarding subclassing, I don't quite get what you are referring to? The example above does not have to do with subclassing.

Comment: @aschepler, I believe that it is related to specializing them depeding on target character width - I have give more info in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason for operator<< taking char is not a member function is that there already are functions defined in ostream which write characters to the stream.

```
basic_ostream& put(Ch c);
basic_ostream& write(const Ch* p, streamsize n);
```

Consequently these operators are made non-member functions which internally uses these two functions.

Answer (score -1):

The first series are member functions, which `return *this` so operator chaining works.

The second series are freestanding functions (which as you say you can add for any class so you can stream them to a `std::ostream`), which have no `this` to return and `return os` instead to make operator chaining work.

Note that both work the same way at a call site.

Comment: my understanding of the question is that the point is why are they separated, not what's the difference

Comment: Asked both to be honest ;)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic the answer is the same, because the questions ask the same thing: the former are part of the class, so already know what `std::ostream&` to return, the latter need an additional argument.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: the confusing part is why not having them all as members or all as non-members.